# Drupal html user id

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Drupal 6.16: I think I have a pretty simple question.  How can I get the current user id and put it in a menu tab.  What I would like to happen is when the user logs in and wants to change their name, email etc to click a menu tab.  I image it would look something like this: http://domain.com/user/{userid}/edit

Thanks in advance!
msindle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more difficult than you would think, because menu items are cached. There is not a straightforward way to create dynamic menu items with the userID in it.

What you *can* do, is write a custom module and imitate the behavior of the 'user' path. With an implementation of hook_menu you create a menu item, with the path 'user/edit' (just like [user_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_menu/6) creates `$items['user']`). Next you create a menu callback `user_edit_page()`, similar to [user_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_page/6), which gets the id of the current user and returns the user edit page:

```
function user_edit_page() {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    menu_set_active_item('user/'. $user->uid .'/edit');
    return menu_execute_active_handler();
  }
  else {
    return drupal_get_form('user_login');
  }
}
```